# Is it worth to preserve timestamps of files during server migration?

Tags: web-hosting, server, migration, 304-not-modified

I am migrating a website from one Linux machine to another with the help of my hosting provider. Is it really worthy to ask them to preserve the timestamps while moving files? In that case, search engine crawlers will not view the pages in the new server as new ones. The new server will return 304 for already downloaded pages by search engine bots. Am I right?